# Random float for random brightness of the LED xCode

Tags: ios, variables, random, led

I tried to use a random float to get a random brightness for the LED of an iPhone.

```
    float x = arc4random() % 11 * 0.1;
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if ([device hasTorch])
    {
        [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
        [device setTorchModeOnWithLevel:x error:NULL];
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work because there is the f missing for the brightness.
What I want to say is the following:

```
    [device setTorchModeOnWithLevel:0.5f error:NULL];
```

after the 0.5 is a f and I think that this is the reason why it doesn't work with the x variable. Is there either any way to add this f to the variable or go a complete other way to set a random brightness?

Thank you!

Comment: The use of the `float` variable `x` is fine. The `f` after `0.5` tells the compiler that the constant is a `float` instead of a `double`. Since `x` is a `float`, you have the correct setup. Verify that `x` is always between 0.0 and 1.0 (which it looks like it should be). What is the actual problem?

Comment: Yeah, basically looks OK.  Verify the actual values you're calculating, and try hard-coding other brightness values to be sure you can actually control what you think you're controlling.

Comment: (But your understanding of floating point is sufficiently weak that you'd be advised to spend some time learning more about it.  Study some reference books.)

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I found the problem, why it wasn't working. But still the random brightness works not every time, sometimes it says: reason: 'setTorchModeOnWithLevel:error: called with an invalid torchLevel (0.000000). How can I fix that? The reason why I do not know much about floats is, that I just began to learn about coding apps. I'm 17 years old and this will be my first app...

Comment: You need probably a year of programming experience before you begin programming apps.

Comment: Yes you are right, but where do I get the experience from, when I do not program apps? I think it's a good start to do so, because I learn all the things by programming some small apps and of course by reading some books...